# Node Winston cria o arquivo de log mas não salva: Attempt to write logs with no transports

Tags: node.js, log

Estou com um problema no winston, segue minhas configurações:

```
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: 'info',
  format: winston.format.json(),
  transport: [
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: './../error.log', level: 'error', json: true }),
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: './../info.log', json: true }),
    new winston.transports.Console()
  ]
});
```

Aqui está o pedaço do código onde solicito para gerar log:

```
.catch(err => logger.error({
   message: 'Erro ao cadastrar usuário',
   data: err
}));
```

Aqui está o alerta que aparece na tentativa de gerar o log:

OBS: estou mandando apenas o começo da mensagem que aparece pois ela é meio grande por causa do json

```
[winston] Attempt to write logs with no transports {"message":"Erro ao cadastrar usuário","data":{"name":
```

Este é meu problema, na tentativa de gerar o log ele me devolve isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fala Pedro, faltou um 's' na configuração do logger.

```js
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: 'info',
  format: winston.format.json(),
  transports: [ //transports ao invés de transport
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: './../error.log', level: 'error', json: true }),
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: './../info.log', json: true }),
    new winston.transports.Console()
  ]
});
```

Corrige aí que vai funcionar corretamente.

Comment: Vou testar aqui, se funcionar marco como certo hheheehe. Se funcionar foi um puta vacilo ahuaha